# Unexpected behavior using "Rx" in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, system.reactive

I observed a behavior I was not expecting. Here is some code to illustrate:

```
class ReactiveService
{
    private readonly ISubject<WorkPayload> observableWork
        = new Subject<WorkPayload>();

    void WorkBeingDone(WorkPayload workPayload)
    {
        this.observableWork.OnNext(workPayload);
    }

    IObservable<WorkPayload> WorkBeingDone() => this.observableWork;
}

class WorkService
{
    private readonly ReactiveService reactiveService;

    public WorkService(ReactiveService reactiveService)
        => this.reactiveService = reactiveService;

    Task DoWork()
    {
        this.reactiveService.WorkBeingDone(new WorkPayload());
        // ... lots of logic here ...
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

class WorkObservingService
{
    private readonly ReactiveService reactiveService;

    public WorkObservingService(ReactiveService reactiveService)
        => this.reactiveService = reactiveService;

    async Task DoSomethingWhenWorkHappens()
    {
        // Now here what I want to do is that on each work being observed,
        // some asynchronous operation is triggered, currently I'm doing it
        // like this, but I'm open to any other suggestion.
        this.reactiveService.WorkBeingDone().Select(
            w => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
            {
                // Do the asynchronous stuff with w...
            })).Concat().Subscribe();
        // Prevent the method from returning or something keep
        // the subscription alive...
    }
}
```

What seems to happen is that when I try to do some asynchronous work in the `Observable.FromAsync`, and it throws, this gets raised all the way back to the `WorkService` and crashes the call to `DoWork`. But in truth, this thing should not care about what happens with the observers of `observableWork`. Is that expected? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: My first observation is that the `ReactiveService` class has two methods that share the same name `WorkBeingDone`, and are doing completely different things. This is very confusing.

Comment: Your code in the question doesn't compile, let alone run. Can you fix that please?

Comment: I'll see if I find the time. The goal was obviously not to have runable code, but just pseudo code as an illustration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observable sequences are awaitable, so you could simply do this:

```
async Task DoSomethingWhenWorkHappens()
{
    await this.reactiveService.WorkBeingDone().Select(
        w => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
        {
            // Do the asynchronous stuff with w...
        })).Concat().DefaultIfEmpty();
}
```

Any error propagated through the sequence will be passed to the resulting `Task`, completing it in a [`Faulted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) state.

The purpose of the `DefaultIfEmpty` operator at the end of the chain is to prevent an `InvalidOperationException`, in case the sequence emits zero elements. The `await` is designed to propagate the last element in the sequence as a result, and so it gets confused when the sequence doesn't contain any elements.

Another option is to [elide](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) the async and await, and just convert the sequence to a `Task` (`.ToTask()`), and return it directly.

> What seems to happen is that when I try to do some asynchronous work in the `Observable.FromAsync`, and it throws, this gets raised all the way back to the `WorkService` and crashes the call to `DoWork`.

I haven't run your code, but my theory is that the error in the `Observable.FromAsync` is escalated to an unhandled exception that crashes the process. I don't expect that you can handle it in the `DoWork`, by wrapping it in `try`/`catch`. This happens because of the naked `.Subscribe()`, that is missing all three handlers (`onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted`). By omitting especially the `onError` handler, you are saying to the Rx that *"Hey! I don't know how to handle a possible error!"*. Guess what, the Rx doesn't know either how to handle this error, so it does what is arguably the most sensible and responsible thing, and rethrows it on the `ThreadPool`, causing your application to crash. Which is not very kind, but on the other hand it's probably better than suppressing the error and throwing it silently into the memory hole.

Comment: It feels wrong that the emitter of the 'work' event has to care about what happens with the observable sequence. Emitting should be fire-and-forget in an event driven system. What if I created a new subject and the only thing I did with this observable is `OnNext` on this new subject, and then did my asynchronous work based on the new observable sequence. Then it shouldn't crash the original `Work` code. Is there a shorthand for such an operation ?

Comment: @JulienDebache the producer and the consumer live inside the same process. What you are asking is to let the producer survive in case the consumer decides to bomb the process (with `Environment.Exit()` for example). You can't do that. If you want that level of resilience, you should put the producer and the consumer is separate processes.

Comment: I think there's a huge difference between calling `Environment.Exit()` and throwing an exception. Exception are usually handled without killing the process, e.g. if the exception is thrown while executing an API endpoint or a remote procedure call, ASP.NET will terminate the request without killing the whole process.

Comment: @JulienDebache so what should happen in your opinion, given that the consumer is using the naked `.Subscribe()` method? What should the Rx do in case the sequence completes with an exception? What should it do with the error, given that you have not provided an error handler?

Comment: Maybe I have my concepts wrong here, but the sequence itself shouldn't be affected by what consumers do with it. If this is not the case, I seriously misunderstood the pattern. How can the producer be decoupled from the consumer if the producer has to wait and check that each consumer does what it has to do successfully before proceeding ?
And to answer your question, if I don't provide a handler, the exception should go unhandled and be rethrown on the consumer side, to be then caught in the container scope (e.g. some controller's middleware pipeline).

Comment: @JulienDebache that's a different question. You could consider posting a new question about this. The short answer is that the Rx is the wrong paradigm for a system where the producer has to know about the state of the consumer, and adjust its own behavior accordingly. The Rx interfaces define pretty clearly the allowed interactions between an observable and an observer. The observer subscribes, and the observable notifies the observer with `OnNext`/`OnError`/`OnCompleted` notifications. There is no provision for passing notifications in the other direction, other than unsubscribing.

Comment: @JulienDebache *"if I don't provide a handler, the exception should go unhandled and be rethrown on the consumer side"* -- What is the consumer side? The producer has to propagate an error, and the only means it has to do it is to invoke the `OnError` method of the subscribed observer. When you don't provide the `onError` handler, the Rx uses something like this as a handler `(error) => throw error;`. If you don't like it, then just provide a handler. Avoid subscribing with the naked `.Subscribe()` method.

Comment: "Rx is the wrong paradigm for a system where the producer has to know about the state of the consumer, and adjust its own behavior accordingly" That's exactly what I mean and why I think the behavior I observe is not correct. So I think we agree. Why would the producer break if a consumer throws an exception if it shouldn't know about the state of the consumer ?

Comment: So yeah, I think in the end I will have to explicitly tell the consumer to not raise the exception on the producer side by giving it an `OnError`, but it seems like it should be the default.

Comment: @JulienDebache the producer breaks because the consumer rethrows the exception as unhandled, causing the process to crash. It's an indirect consequence of both of them living in the same process. If you think that the correct behavior of the naked `.Subscribe()` should be to suppress the exception, it's too late to change it now, even if you were able to convince the owners of the library about it, which I doubt. But it's always possible to write your own extension method for `IObservable<T>` sequences, for example `.SubscribeEx()`, with the behavior that you prefer.

Comment: @JulienDebache here it is, enjoy.  `static IDisposable SubscribeEx<T>(this IObservable<T> s) => s.Subscribe(_ => { }, _ => { });`

Comment: Okay I created a small running project to test out all of the above. I think the `.Concat().DefaultIfEmpty()` is what I'm looking for. Therefore, I will accept your answer, thanks for your patience.